# How can I make my wiki clock dynamic?

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

How can I make the clocks on http://torwiki.com/page/User:Technical_13/SandBox#Dynamic_Clock dynamic to show the actual current time in multiple time zones... I am an administrator, so I have access to MediaWiki:common.js, which is activated.  I have read tutorials to show a single clock, but how would a make it work with multiple clocks?  I want to be able to create a template that will allow me to define the timezone, and have it display the current time in that zone.  I could wrap it in a `<span>` with an id or name to identify the timezone I want, but how do I make it work for multiple clocks.  Keep in mind, that using MediaWiki style wiki, I can not put any javascript calls in-line for each instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a [million JavaScript clock scripts](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript%20clocks) on line.  It sounds like your real issue is that you want it to show user local time, not server time -- but you've forgotten that the JavaScript runs in the user's browser.  Calling `Date()` will automagically give you the user's local time.